# Como filtrar dados por categoria no Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, api, framework

Eu estou tentando filtrar os dados provenientes de uma consulta com base nos parâmetros `gestorId`, `projectManagerId` e `recursoId`, no entanto, não tenho certeza se esta é a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Eu também preciso desses parâmetros para funcionar como categoria e os dados a serem filtrados de acordo com o item selecionado, se selecionado `gestorId`, o resultado deve ser apenas os projetos que estão naquele `gestorId`, se selecionado `gestorId` e `recursoId`, retorna apenas os projetos que conter esses parâmetros, como se fosse um filtro em cascata, no entanto, não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

```
public override IEnumerable<Projeto> AllByFilter(int? gestorId, int? projectManagerId, int? recursoId) =>

    _appContext.Projetos.Select(n => new Projeto
       {
           Id = n.Id,
           ProjectManager = n.ProjectManager,
           Gestor = n.Gestor,
           ProjetoRecursos = n.ProjetoRecursos
                              .Select(q => new ProjetoRecurso { Recurso = q.Recurso })
                              .Where(x => x.Recurso.Id == recursoId).ToList()
       })
      .Where(x => x.Gestor.Id == gestorId && x.ProjectManager.Id == projectManagerId)
      .ToList();
```

Retorno da consulta:

/api/projeto/filter/3/1/3

```
[
{
    "ativo": true,
    "id": 25,
    "codigo": null,
    "proposta": null,
    "descricao": null,
    "quantidadeHoras": 0,
    "dataContratacao": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "observacao": null,
    "projectManager": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Benito"
    },
    "projetoRecursos": [],
    "faturamento": null,
    "gestor": {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Jose",
        "projetos": [],
        "usuarios": []
    }
},
{
    "ativo": true,
    "id": 28,
    "codigo": null,
    "proposta": null,
    "descricao": null,
    "quantidadeHoras": 0,
    "dataContratacao": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "observacao": null,
    "projectManager": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Benito"
    },
    "projetoRecursos": [],
    "faturamento": null,
    "gestor": {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Jose",
        "projetos": [],
        "usuarios": []
    }
}
```

]

Tentei este aqui também, mas sem sucesso:

```
 public override IEnumerable<Projeto> AllByFilter(int? gestorId, int? projectManagerId,int? recursoId) =>
           _appContext.Projetos
           .Include(x => x.ProjetoRecursos.Where(i=>i.Recurso.Id==recursoId)).ThenInclude(x =>x.Recurso)
           .Include(x => x.Gestor)
           .Where(x=>x.GestorId==gestorId && x.ProjectManagerId==projectManagerId);
```

Erro:

> The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from ProjetoRecurso i in x.ProjetoRecursos where (Convert([i].Recurso.Id, Nullable`1) == __recursoId_0) select [i]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.